# UWP Get Uniqe Usb Pendrive Id

Tags: c#, uwp

I have problem with UWP app.  I want to get an uniqe id of USB Pendrive. Thanks to it I will be able to distinguish to which USB Pendrive i should send files. Of course I can get FolderRelitiveId from KnownFolders.RemovabelDevices but this value is not uniqe. I think i need GUID, VID or PID. Is there any way to get all USB Storage Devices and all their info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result for this problem is dead simple. You can initialize StorageDevice with DeviceInformation ID. Then you are able to get StoragFolder from this. Do not forget to add reference to: Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could use [`Windows.Devices.Enumeration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration) API to get portable Storage device. For more detail you could refer [**DeviceEnumaerationAndPairing**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) scenario 2.

```
handlerAdded = new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>(async (watcher, deviceInfo) =>
{
    // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
    await rootPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
    {
        ResultCollection.Add(new DeviceInformationDisplay(deviceInfo));

        rootPage.NotifyUser(
            String.Format("{0} devices found.", ResultCollection.Count),
            NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    });
});
```

Then you could get unique id from `deviceInfo` object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to get unique id but i have other problem. With KnownFolder.RemovableDevices i can get Path an real name of device but I am unable to get properties like in DeviceInformation. Is there any way to get path of this device from DeviceInfromation ? Is there any special property which I can get from DeviceInformation ?

Comment: `DeviceInfromation` does not provide path property for portable storage device, But you could get `RemovableDevices` with  DeviceInformation  id then get path property.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Are you thinking about something like retriving additional properties for folder ? I found solution which is using StorageDevice. I can get USB Storage Folder by getting folder from StorageDevice by DeviceInformation Id(For people who will have problem add reference called "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP").

Comment: That is I want to say *getting folder from StorageDevice by DeviceInformation Id*. If you have solution please post your answer and you could mark yourself to convenient people who visit this thread later.